# Consulting with other consultants

Tags: external-project-members, subcontractor

Question to the braintrust.

How do you handle whether to offload API programming and design when another consultant asks you? I'm in a situation where I have to do development against an API that I consult on. The consultant is developing an internal application but we have a natural touchpoint as he will need to send me objects so that it will persist in the vendor application.

He doesn't have experience with the API. I do. I can develop this interface and the logic aroundi

Comment: Hi, welcome to PMSE, the site for expert and enthusiast project managers. I'm confused by your question. It almost looks like you meant to add more but then just posted your question without finishing your last sentence. Can you edit your question and add more clarifying details? Thank you, and welcome to our site!

Answer (score 2):

This should always come down to the commercial arrangements between the parties. You should only do what you are contracted to do, but that should not stop you making an offer to do more, and then abiding by the decision after your offer has been made. You might like to consider making two offers: one for what you have been asked to do, and the other to do the whole job (with the other guy as prime contractor, probably). What you should NOT do is bypass the other consultant and go directly to the client: your reputation is worth more than the value of the business you will pick up, and you should avoid getting a reputation as someone who steals work that has been won by someone else's efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have time and the commercial details (payment, etc.) are acceptable to you, go for it. After all you already consulted on the API so you might be in the best position to also implement it.